# Sorting Numbers into Groups

Tags: algorithms, math-software, recursive-algorithms, sorting

I have a list of numbers
N1,N2,N3…………

The list must be grouped into groups of 3 
G1,G2,G3…..

The sum of Each Group must be >= X, The sum of Each Group must be <= Y

I understand that there may be some numbers left over that cannot be grouped.

1. What is the best way to group the numbers such that the maximum
   number of groups can be created ?
2. What is the best way to group the numbers such that groups can be
   created in the least amount of time  ?
3. Is there a best case combination of requirement 1 and 2 ?

thanks
Damo

Comment: There are a few things which need clarifying on this - is our list of numbers infinite? When you have the inequality in the third line, I don't understand why you have that the sum of the elements in $G_i$ must be greater than $X$, but also that $X$ is less than $Y$ - what is the significance of $Y$? Do you instead mean that the sum of the elements of $G_i$ must lie between two values? Also, what happens if we have that the total sum of the numbers do not satisify the constraints?

Comment: is our list of numbers infinite? No - I have clarified line 3 - Your assumption is correct in that the sum must lie between the two valus X and Y - Finally if the total sum of 3 numbers do not satisfy the constraints then they are not a solution (i.e no a valid group)

Comment: does each group contain exactly 3 elements?

Comment: @ miracle173 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write proper pseudocode, but I think that a near-optimal algorithm would just pair the largest numbers with the smallest ones.

First, you can't have a best/worst case for condition 1 without knowing the range of your data set. The worst case is always zero (all N are greater than Y) and the best case is 100%

My recommended algorithm:

1 - Sort N, a quicksort algorithm has time complexity O(n log n), from this point I will refer to the smallest value in the list as N(1) and the largest as N(t)

2 - If N(t) + N(t-1) + N(1) < X, remove N(1), repeat until false

3 - If N(t) + N(1) + N(2) > Y, remove N(t), repeat until false

4 - Pair N(t) + N(t-1) + N(1) or N(t) + N(1) + N(2) into a group, whichever is closest to (X+Y)/2, return to step 2.

This is almost definitely not the best algorithm, but any major improvements will probably involve some fairly complex optimization, and I wouldn't even be sure where to begin. I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: hi, as you say this helps a bit but no dice - i need to figure out how to get the best solution.

Comment: If you have a small enough sample size, you could do an exhaustive search but it would scale poorly. I'm sorry I couldn't help more, I'll think about it and see if I can come up with something better.

Comment: Note, steps 1 to 3 are necessary for all strategies, as the optimal groups necessarily depend on the (sorted) numbers and 2,3 are "trivial" elimination strategies.